# Jquery DataTables - onClick function to get multiple cell values of specific columns

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to be able to click on a column cell and also retrieve the cell value of another defined column of the same row in order to store both values in an array which can be passed on.

Here's what I tried:

```
$('#datatab tbody').on('click', 'tr td.lastname', function () {
    var data = dt.column(0).cell(this).data();
    console.log(data);
    var data1 = dt.columns([0, 1]).data();
    console.log(data1);

....
}
```

If the table had a lastname and firstname column (not always adjacent), I would need to grab those two cell values based on the column index for example or some css class.

Hope you can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Try $('#datatab').row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data(); for data selection under your click function. This will give full row data.

Comment: didn't work for me. "row" is undefined...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data of entire row on click of specific column using the below function

```
//Function for handling click event
$('body').on('click', '#datatab tbody tr td.lastname', function () {

  rowData = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();

  console.log("First Name : ", rowData[0], "\t\tLast Name : ", rowData[1], "\t\tAge : ", rowData[2]);
 });
```

I have created the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/0yemnxq9/1/ for the same.Please have a look.

Comment: very nice and even simpler than I thought :-) Thank you.